# Referencing an html input element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following (repeating) html:

```
<tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td><a href="#">Click me<a/></td>
    <td><form><input type="hidden" value="4"/></form></td>
</tr>
```

Using jQuery on the click event of the link I want to retrieve the value of the input element. I have tried all kinds of parents(), children(), nextAll(), prev() combinations but I can not get the value of the input element.

Here is a link to my testing functions. [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/statv/)

Additionally how would i retrieve the text of the first td element?

Thanks a lot for helping me achieve this.
Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get to the `td` from the `a`, then [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get to the following `td`, and then [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get to the `input` element:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).parent().next().find("input").val();
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/statv/5/).

To get the text from the first `td` you can take pretty much the same approach, but use [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) instead of `next`.

Also, seeing as you have several repetitions of the HTML snippet, it's probably going to be more efficient to bind the `click` event handler higher up the DOM tree (maybe you already are, you haven't posted any JS so I don't know):

```
$("table").on("click", "a", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Makes sense. Frustrating how something so simple can be such an issue. :-) The binding higher up in the DOM tree was something else i was wondering about, so this is great.

Comment: The table code, breaks all my jQuery code. Additionally, how would i use $(this) to refer to the 'a' element, as i assume this would now refer to the table.

Comment: @MichaelFrey - No, `this` will refer to the `a` element that has been clicked. Are you using jQuery 1.7 or above? The `on` method was added in 1.7. If you're using an older version, look at `delegate` instead, which will achieve the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I was using a previous version. It works now after i updated it.

Answer (score 0):

My usual approach to these things is to use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to go back to some common container and then [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to come back down:

```
​$('a').click(function() {
    var $input = $(this).closest('tr').find('input');
    // Do something with $input.val()
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Zh6Zk/

The `closest`/`find` approach withstands DOM structure changes fairly well so you don't have to worry that much about moving things around in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

it will give you the input value

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.myAnchor').click(function(e){
    var parentNode = $(this).parent();
    var valueOfInput = $(parentNode).next().children('input').val();
            alert(valueOfInput);
});
});
```

html:

```
<form>
<table>    
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="myAnchor">Click me</a></td>
        <td><input type=hidden value="4"/></td>
     </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you getting the `tagName`? You already have a jQuery object containing the element you want. Also, you shouldn't use `attr` to get the value. Use `val` instead.

Comment: thanks for correcting me, for tagname.. i was just checking that i am getting the correct tag or not, let me edit it

Comment: No problem. That's better now, but there is no need to pass `parentNode` into jQuery since it's already a jQuery object. You can just do `parentNode.next()`.